# problems with ajax, only displays the header and not the records

Tags: php, ajax

## I have a problem with this code.

I created a drop-down menu that directly takes the categories from the database. so far everything is ok.
When, however, I choose the type, it only displays the header of the table and not the records.
can you tell me why?

I think the problem is "q" but I do not know how to modify it becouse I tried to do the query without 'Where' and correctly displays the records.

```
<html>
<script>
var xmlhttp;

function mostraInfo(str)
{


xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
{
alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
return;
}

var url="2.php";
url=url+"?q="+str;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
}
return null;
}
</script>

<form>
Seleziona Categoria:
<select name="users" onChange="mostraInfo(this.value)">
<option value="">Seleziona categoria:</option>
<?php 
//Seleziono quelli che sono i dipendenti
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbname="my_lisipcivicsense";
$dbuser="lisipcivicsense";
$dbpsw="";

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbname, $dbpsw);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$query = "SELECT distinct tipologia FROM gruppi ORDER BY tipologia ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($riga = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='$riga[nome_gruppo]'> $riga[tipologia] </option>";
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="info"></div>
</html>
```

----- file 2(2.php)------

```
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbname="my_lisipcivicsense";
$dbuser="lisipcivicsense";
$dbpsw="";

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbname, $dbpsw);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM gruppi  WHERE tipologia = '".$q."'" ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th> Nome Gruppo </th>
<th> Email </th>
<th> Tipologia </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nome_gruppo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email_gruppo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['tipologia'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is the query,you are using double quotation inside single quote, Try this instead :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM gruppi  WHERE tipologia = '{$q}'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code, you've provided, I don't see where is $q defined.
So I believe in the end your query looks like:

```
"SELECT * FROM gruppi  WHERE tipologia = ''"
```

You can always dump something in order to check what's really going on by inserting temporary code like this:

```
var_dump($sql);exit;
```

Just don't forget to remove/comment it after debugging ;)

## Solution:

You need to get "q" parameter from the GET request:

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q'], $con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM gruppi  WHERE tipologia = '".$q."'" ;
```

*mysql_real_escape_string* function is there to prevent some simple SQL injections. Please check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

But it would be better to use at least [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead of outdated "mysql_" functions.

#### Complete code of 2.php with fix:

```php
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbname="my_lisipcivicsense";
$dbuser="lisipcivicsense";
$dbpsw="";

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbname, $dbpsw);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q'], $con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM gruppi  WHERE tipologia = '".$q."'" ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th> Nome Gruppo </th>
<th> Email </th>
<th> Tipologia </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nome_gruppo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email_gruppo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['tipologia'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Ho inserito i comandi che mi hanno detto ma la query viene fuori in questo modo:                                                                          
    string(42) "SELECT * FROM gruppi WHERE tipologia = ''".                    
is this line of code correct?                                       
    xmlhttp.send(null);

Comment: I've added complete code of 2.php with my fix. Just copy-paste it and try if it works.

Comment: it does not work ... I think there is some mistake here:  (1.PHP )                   
 var url="2.php;
url=url+"?q="+str;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}          
because array get is empty.    also I can not understand how the user's choice can go in $ GET _ ["q"]

Comment: Everything that goes after "?" in URL gets into $_GET superglobal array. If you have empty $_GET array, then indeed you are doing something wrong when sending an ajax request. Please learn more at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php .

You can also check what does your JS code send by opening developer tools in Chrome and selcting Network tab.